# How to launch simulator via VS Code and solve issue: Could not build the application for the simulator?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, ios-simulator

I have an error, when I am trying to launch simulator by running main.dart.

The error message is following:

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            5.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Uncategorized (Xcode): Scheme Runner is not currently configured for the build action.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.
Exited

If I click on IOS -> launch in XCode it works fine.

Flutter Doctor output:

```
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.14.0-12.0.pre.62, on macOS 
    13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64,locale en-SE)
    [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android 
    SDK version 33.0.2)
    [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    [✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    [✓] VS Code (version 1.72.2)
    [✓] Connected device (3 available)
    [✓] Network resources

    • No issues found!
```

Does anyone know how to solve VS Code simulator launch problem?

Thank you!